# How does Linux Mint 13 GUI (Cinnamon) know which users have administrator privileges?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, privileges

Recently Cinnamon crashed. And I can no longer:

- Change settings of network manager
- Mount any external disks (except by sudo mount ... on command line)
- Shutdown (only can log out)
- Click "unlock" on any system setting for admin options

I renamed my home folder, deleted myself, created a new user, moved my data from my backup home directory(except dotfolders and dotfiles like .config, .dmrc, .pulse, .gconf, .gnome2 ...) and re logged in. This way, I got my privileges back. After a while, Cinnamon crashed again and I have the same problem. And the following does not work:

- Login from text terminal.
- $ rm -rf .config/ .dbus/ .gconf/ .gnome2 .gnome2_private/ .linuxmint/ .local/ .pki/
- reboot

And I still do not have my privileges. How are the GUI side of privileges handled and how can I get them back? Probably some configuration file is missing or has the wrong permissions.